# Facebook Login Screen in different Locale

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I have a php application which uses facebook php sdk to integrate Facebook login within the app. I have 5 versions of the app with 5 language settings, but the problem is the facebook Login popup page always opens in English and pop-up opening handler is part of SDK itself, I cant figure out which configuration would lead to the solution.

Earlier, I had managed to show the "Log in to Facebook" button in 5 different languages by including 5 different Javascripts. But I could not find any solution opening the Login Screen in various Languages... Please help

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use Javascript SDK for login. In Javascript SDK you can load different SDK's which have different locales. Just look at this url: `connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js`

Change en_US to any locale. So login screen will be localized as you wish.

**Update:**
It seems that facebook later decided to change this behaviour. According to [internationalization document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/) and [this blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/394/) applications cannot control facebook's locale. Only thing you can do is checking user's locale and adapting your application's locale to Facebook's.

Comment: I have already included connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js in English version, connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js for French version, they just change the Button Text to native Languages, not the Login Screen. Need Help.

Comment: It seems that applications cannot change Facebook locale. It's user defined. Updated my answer.